# DJANGO: replace a combobox created successfully in a list of views.py, with one created with classes in forms.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm new to Django. I saw that there are 2 different ways to create comboboxes and forms. I would like to replace my current mode, already successfully created, with another mode.

**WAY 1 (works well, correctly):**
I have a combobox that works fine, created by putting the items in a list in `views.py`, for example: `color_choices = ("Red","Blue","Black", "Orange")`. I am currently using this mode.

**WAY 2:**
Way 1 works fine correctly for me, but only now I've seen that it's possible to create comboboxes also by creating a `forms.py` file, importing `from django import forms`, and then writing the items in the `classes`. The combobox uses a static list

**QUESTION:** How can I modify my code (which uses `Way 1`) and replace it with forms.py with `Way 2` classes? I would like to use the classes and the forms.py file, and I would not like to use the items in the views.py file (it works correctly fine with Way 1). Can you show me how I can use Way 2 correctly?

Which of the two ways is more correct and better in terms of loading speed? Thank you!

P.S: the comboboxes are database independent. they don't use any database.

This is the working code of Way 1:

**WAY 1 CODE**

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
  color_choices = ("Red","Blue","Black", "Orange")
  message =''
  if request.method =="POST":
    message = request.POST.get('color')

  context = {'message':message,'color_choices':color_choices}
  return render(request, 'app1/home.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
  <form name="Item_Django" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="color" class="form-select" >
      {% for i in color_choices %}
      <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="msg" cols="30" rows="10">{{message}}</textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**CODE NOT WORKING OF WAY 2**

This is what I would use:

```
from django import forms

class SimpleCombobox(forms.Form):
    Col1 = 'Red'
    Col2 = 'Blue'
    Col3 = 'Black'
    Col4 = 'Orange'
      
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        (Col1, u"Red"),
        (Col2, u"Blue"),
        (Col3, u"Black"),
        (Col4, u"Orange"),
    )
    cities = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)


class SimpleTextbox(forms.Form):
    coverletter = forms.CharField(required=False,
              widget=forms.Textarea(
                # rows and colums of the textarea
                attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
```

Comment: Your **way 2** is not working because although you are creating the forms, you are not importing them into the views, and then sending them in the context to your template.  But even if you get that to work, in your case, I think using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) is a much better approach, and the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) are excellent and will give you what I think you want.  In the end, you can make *one* class with the fields of `cities`, `coverletter` and `COLOR_CHOICES`.

Comment: @raphael I know why Mode2 doesn't work, but I can't get it to work properly. I'm just starting out with Django. This is why I had asked the question on stackoverflow. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve those things in Django **form** like this...

#### form.py

```
class SimpleCombobox(forms.Form):
    COLOR_CHOICES = (
        ('Red', "Red"),
        ('Blue', "Blue"),
        ('Black', "Black"),
        ('Orange', "Orange"),
    )
    color = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES)


class SimpleTextbox(forms.Form):
    coverletter = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
```

#### views.py

```
def DemoView(request):
  form1 = SimpleCombobox()
  form2 = SimpleTextbox()
  if request.method =="POST":
    picked = SimpleCombobox(request.POST)
    if picked.is_valid():
      val_pick = picked.cleaned_data.get('color')
      print(val_pick,"====>")
      if val_pick == 'Red':
        form2 = SimpleTextbox(initial={'coverletter':val_pick})
      elif val_pick == 'Blue':
        form2 = SimpleTextbox(initial={'coverletter':val_pick})
      elif val_pick == 'Black':
        form2 = SimpleTextbox(initial={'coverletter':val_pick})       
      else:
        form2 = SimpleTextbox(initial={'coverletter':val_pick})
  context = {'form1':form1,'form2':form2}
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#### output

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to reply so late. It was difficult papers and I was short on time. I tried your code, but there is a problem: the combobox remains empty with no color inside. In the function def DemoView I replaced your index.html with my app1/home.html. In urls.py I put this in urlpatterns: path('home/', views.DemoView, name='home'). Then I imported this into views.py: from .forms import LoginForm, SimpleCombobox, SimpleTextbox. I don't understand why the combobox remains empty. can you help me? Thank you